# PFQuery find object with null value

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery, back4app, pfobject

I would like to fetch all objects where `paidDate` is not set yet.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"Salary")        
query.whereKey("paidDate", equalTo: nil)
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
...
```

I don't want to put a specific date to a query. The fact that `paidDate` was not set means that salary was not paid, so I would like to get all unpaid salaries.

Is this possible to make such query?

Comment: Your current query should work, is it not working?

Comment: @TanzimChowdhury it does not even on compilation level as I can pass nil there. whereKey function does not allow to use nil values in it. It's kind of just example what I want